# get user inactivity in react native

Tags: react-native

What I want is to display a Image if user does not interact with the app for 1 minute.
I have tried implementing it by setting timers on all the user events like onPress onSwipe etc on all the elements. But handling those is a complex process.
Then I tried out using InteractionManager but that also didn't work out. 
What I want to know is there any way I can get to know if any user event has occurred?

Comment: I posted an issue on react-native github and got the following response 
 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14287

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally, I did it using PanResponder. And It works flawlessly. It takes key presses ans swipes and drags.

Expo Link : https://snack.expo.io/Sy8ulr8B-

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, PanResponder, View, StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity, Text , Image} from 'react-native';


export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    show : false
  };
  _panResponder = {};
  timer = 0;
  componentWillMount() {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({

      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => {
        this.resetTimer()
        return true
      },
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => { this.resetTimer() ; return false},
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => false,
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => true,
      onShouldBlockNativeResponder: () => false,
    });
    this.timer = setTimeout(()=>this.setState({show:true}),5000)
  }

  resetTimer(){
    clearTimeout(this.timer)
    if(this.state.show)
    this.setState({show:false})
    this.timer = setTimeout(()=>this.setState({show:true}),5000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={styles.container}
        collapsable={false}
        {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>

        {
          this.state.show ? <Text style={{fontSize:30}}>Timer Expired : 5sec</Text> : null
        }

        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Image style={{width: 300, height: 300}} source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}} />
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <Button
          title="Here is a button for some reason"
          onPress={() => {}}  
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  }
});
```

Comment: Same question as above, any views?

Comment: Doing this in every component could lead to very strange behavior, depending on how you're handling navigation in your app. Without knowing, you could be spawning multiple timers (one each time you navigate to a new component).
I was using react navigation, so I created a Custom Navigator (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html) to wrap the StackNavigator of the screens where I wanted to check for inactivity.

Comment: @tonysta will adding this to every screen cause issue, as their set timeout running?

Comment: @DavidCastillo Can you provide an example of the custom navigator you created? Running into the same situation.

Comment: Perfect solution, working great I have used your logic and made a custom hook using same, so that I can reuse it across multiple component, also tweaked it a little to make sure setTimeout should be cleared and not run multiple times either, while navigating from screen

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I implemented inactive listener with react-navigation Custom Navigator.
I used react-native PanResponder to detect touch activities.
Since this is mounted to the root of the app, there won't be any issues with mounting setTimout in multiple places.

```js
import React, {useCallback, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {useKeycloak} from '@react-keycloak/native';
import {
  NavigationHelpersContext,
  useNavigationBuilder,
  StackRouter,
} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {View, PanResponder} from 'react-native';

const CustomNavigator = ({initialRouteName, children, screenOptions}) => {
  const {state, navigation, descriptors} = useNavigationBuilder(StackRouter, {
    children,
    screenOptions,
    initialRouteName,
  });
  const [keycloak] = useKeycloak();
  const timerId = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    resetInactivityTimeout();
  }, [resetInactivityTimeout]);

  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => {
        resetInactivityTimeout();
      },
    }),
  ).current;


  const resetInactivityTimeout = useCallback(() => {
    clearTimeout(timerId.current);
    timerId.current = setTimeout(() => {
      // action after user has been detected idle
      // ex: logout from the app
    }, 30000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationHelpersContext.Provider value={navigation}>
      <View style={{flex: 1}} {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
        {descriptors[state.routes[state.index].key].render()}
      </View>
    </NavigationHelpersContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default CustomNavigator;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created module `react-native-inactivity` for this purpose. By using this module you can actually get if the app is inactive for 1 minute. You can use in this way.

```js
import ReactNativeInactivity from "react-native-inactivity";

export default function App() {
  const [showImage, setShowImage] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <ReactNativeInactivity
        isActive={true}
        onInactive={() => setShowImage(true)}
        timeForInactivity={60000} //1 mint in ms
        restartTimerOnActivityAfterExpiration={false}
        loop={false}
        style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: "grey" }}>
        <YOUR_NAV_HERE/>
      </ReactNativeInactivity>
      { showImage ? <YourImage /> : null }
    </View>
  );
}
```

You can also manage other props according to your requirement. Even After showing the image you can actually deactivate the timer through state if you wish.

If this solution helped you just thumbs up and give me a star at repository.
For more refer to: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-inactivity