# Reveal react-native-modal with setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, react-native, modal-dialog

So I am new to React Native and currently building an app that will shows a modal when you go idle for a few seconds, and there is 'YES' button in the modal when you pressed it, it will refresh the timer and shows the modal again, and if you do nothing with the modal it goes to next page, is that possible to do that? Thanks in advance, btw I'm using react-native-modal

here is my code

AlertModal.js

```js
const AlertModal = (props) => {

    return (
        <Modal isVisible={props.visible}  >
            <View style={styles.dialogBox}>
                <View style={styles.text}>
                    <Text style={styles.status}>You ran out of time</Text>
                    <Text>still editing?</Text>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.close}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>YES</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </Modal>
    )
}

AlertModal.propTypes = {
    visible: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    close: PropTypes.func
}

export default AlertModal;
```

FormInput.js

```js
class FormInput extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const { fields, error } = props;

        this.state = this.createState(fields, error);

        //bind functions
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.sessionTimeout = this.sessionTimeout.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.timer = setTimeout(this.onSubmit, 5000); //auto reset after 60 seconds of inactivity
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
    
       onSubmit() {
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
        this.setState({ submitted: true }); //shows activity indicator

        const data = this.state;
        const result = validate(data, this.props.validationLang);

        if (!result.success) {
            this.setState({ error: result.error });
            this.setState({ submitted: false });     //terminate activity indicator
        }
        else
            this.props.onSubmit(this.extractData(data), () => this.setState({ submitted: false }));
    }
```

Comment: Plase refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45103853/11212074

Comment: well it's kind of not what i want actually

Comment: Please precise what part you are having difficulties with