# React Native inactivity logout

Tags: react-native, expo

Hello i want to make an inactivity log out for my app, so if the user doesn't do anything on the app for 3 minutes, the app will comeback to the login screen.

I'm using expo, react native navigation V6, and functional components.

i haven't been able to figure how to do it. please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get user inactivity in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196459/get-user-inactivity-in-react-native)

Comment: Your solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78243741/13666027

Answer (score 1):

I think i was able to do that on an app that i made 1 year ago, i think this code can you help you.

```js
const ManageExpenses = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    if (mounted) {
      tick();
    }
    return () => mounted = false;
  }, []);

  function tick() {
    let timer = setInterval(() => {
      setTime((prevTime) => (prevTime = prevTime + 1));
    }, 1000);
  }

  if (time >= 10) {
    navigation.goBack();
  }

  function pressHandler() {
    setTime(0)
  }
  
  return (
    <Pressable onPress={pressHandler} style={styles.container}>
    </Pressable>
  );
  
  export default ManageExpenses;
  
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    }
 })
```

I created a Pressable component around the entire screen and it redefine the time state when the user press the screen. I hope this will help you!